.net 7 Add a property to an existing JSON file postActions
How can I add json property to my appsettings.json
during creating a new project from custom template in .NET 7?
What have I tried:
https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Post-Action-Registry#add-a-property-to-an-existing-json-file
I have added the following code to the .template.config
"postActions": [{
  "description": "Add LogLevel property to deployment.json",
  "actionId": "210D431B-A78B-4D2F-B762-4ED3E3EA9025",
  "args": {
    "jsonFileName": ".\\appsettings.json",
    "parentPropertyPath": "moduleConfiguration:edgeAgent:properties.desired",
    "newJsonPropertyName": "LogLevel123",
    "newJsonPropertyValue": "Information123"
  },
  "manualInstructions": [{
    "text": "Add a new property 'LogLevel' with value 'Information' to '.\\deployment.json' under existing property 'moduleConfiguration:edgeAgent:properties.desired'"
  }],
  "continueOnError": true
}]


My Template Structure:
MyConsoleApp/                       # Root directory for the solution
│
├── .template.config/               # Template configuration folder
│   └── template.json               # Template definition file
│
├── MyConsoleApp/                   # Project folder (this is what you're templating)
│   ├── Properties/
│   │   └── launchSettings.json
│   ├── obj/                        # Generated; not part of the template
│   ├── bin/                        # Generated; not part of the template
│   ├── Program.cs                  # Main program file
│   └── MyConsoleApp.csproj         # Project file
│   └── appsettings.json and etc
└── MyConsoleApp.sln                # Solution file

and it's not working.
